# Find INI File From application path and Read INI File in Compact framework C#

Tags: compact-framework, ini

i Want To Find Confic.INI File From Application path and i want get values, i mean read INI file data to string...

My Code
{

StreamReader Sdr=new StreamReader( System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)+"\Confic.INI")

//HERE I AM NOT GETTING APPLICATION PATH AND FILE NAME)//

String data=file.readline();
}

Please help me..

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

To find application dir I use:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

So you can use:

```
string assname=Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location; // This is the assembly's name
Path.GetDirectoryName(assname); // This is the assembly dir
string filename=Path.Combine(dir,"Config.ini");
string[] ini = File.ReadAddLines(filename);
```

Comment: thank you... but path.GetDirectoryname(HERE Assembly i am not getting

Comment: @Prashanth Joy: what do you mean with _HERE Assembly I am not getting_? Did you include System.Reflection?

Comment: @Prashanth Joy: which is the value of **assname** in my edited code?

Comment: String path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase.Replace("file:///", ""))+"\\Confic.INI";
StreamReader Sdr=new StreamReader(path);